# Bash - Moving files using destination from txt file

Tags: bash, shell, mv

I have a text file (log.txt) containing a list of file paths where I want files to end up.

```
/root/NewDir/Testfile.txt
/root/NewDir/Testfile2.txt
/root/NewDir2/Alsoatest.txt
...
```

The files are currently sat in the same location as log.txt

```
/root/Dustbin/log.txt
/root/Dustbin/Testfile.txt
/root/Dustbin/Testfile2.txt
/root/Dustbin/Alsoatest.txt
...
```

I am trying to create a script that can take just the filename and will move the specified file to the location stated in the log.txt file.

For example:

```
# restore Testfile.txt
```

The result should be Testfile.txt moving from /root/Dustbin/... to /root/NewDir/...

I am a total newbie at bash / shellscript and have tried researching this for hours but am totally stumped! 
I know I need to use the 'mv' function but am not sure how to populate the destination with those specified in the log.txt file by matching the filenames!

Would anyone have any idea or be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: SO, does not exist to write your code, this question might get you started in the right direction http://superuser.com/questions/538306/move-a-list-of-filesin-a-text-file-to-a-directory as well as the `basename` function. If you run into issues add the problematic code to this question and we'll help

Comment: Loop through `log.txt` and call `basename` on each filename, which returns the filename without the directory. If that matches the name you're trying to restore, then use the filename as the destination for `mv`.

Comment: In addition to other suggestions on trying search for similar answered questions and researching `mv`, look into [mmv](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/GNU-Linux-Tools-Summary/html/x4055.htm) and rename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
#!/bin/bash 

dustbin="/root/Dustbin"
file="$1"

mv $dustbin/$file $(grep "/$file$" $dustbin/log.txt)
```

Depending of your requirements, you could improve the script adding a "mkdir" before the "mv", ... .

Comment: Thanks for that
This has helped point me in the right direction and get my script working closer to how I want it